# InfluxDB - How can i limit the measures that an user can read by their tags?

Tags: security, time-series, influxdb, database-permissions, grafana

I have some data that is collected by several sensors. Some users may own many of this sensors. So, i want to keep all the measures in a single database in InfluxDB. To differentiate the sensors i pretend to add some tags (such as 'sensor_id=aaa', 'sensor_id=bbb', etc).

But, i have read the documentation and it seems that there's not a security option or something that allows me to restrict to any given user to the sensors that he owns or has permissions to read.

In version 0.8 exists [this option](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.8/api/administration/#limiting-user-access) that seems to do that, but in version 0.9 (which i'm using) i cant find nothing similar.

I want to use Grafana to allow people to create some dashboards, thats why i need InfluxDB, but i'm stuck in this part.

Does exist some configuration/feature that helps me to do so?
Should i try a diferent aproach? Any suggestion?
There's some other tool that would be more helpful in my case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are open to try another time series database that supports role based access control? In your example, a security object would be = sensor to which you would grant access to principals (users). Users will be able to view data only for sensors that they are authorized to access.

Comment: Any of those databases would work with Grafana? That's an important requeriment. That's why i'm insterested in InfluxDB. But if other database can do that, there's no problem in change it.

Comment: Disclosure: I work for Axibase. Axibase Time Series Database has built-in RBAC security, built-in visualization (widgets) and Grafana storage driver https://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/visualization/grafana/ But... if you're planning to use the same shared Grafana instance for multiple users, the RBAC security implemented in the database is of no use. You have to implement security in Grafana.

Comment: So i could add some Grafana users that relates to the Axibase's users, using the Grafana Api. The RBAC would help me to restrict the users to only some records, as i explained above?

Comment: RBAC allows you to create multiple user accounts in the database and grant granular access (at the sensor level) to those users based on their permissions. I have to withdraw my recommendation since I have no idea how end-user security is implemented in Grafana. The storage driver will be shared, so I don't think RBAC in ATSD is of any use in your scenario.

Comment: Oh, i understand. I'm gonna try a possible solution, i dont know if it would be useful to you any feedback, but i'll comment my result. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: I could do what i needed with Axibase and Grafana, i had to do some changes in the driver and add the allowed users in the tags of each sensor entity.

Comment: Thank you for https://github.com/grafana/grafana-plugins/pull/67, we have a similar PR open https://github.com/grafana/grafana-plugins/pull/55 but things are moving a bit slower in the Grafana plugin repo. Let us know via support contacts if run into ANY issues with this integration.

Comment: Duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127291/influxdb-how-can-i-limit-the-measures-that-a-user-can-read-by-their-tags.